# Has Aragorn ever expressed fear?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings

In The Return of the King, just before the Battle of the Morannon near the Black Gate, Aragorn gives the following (now famous) speech before his army:

> Transcript:
>   Sons of Gondor!
>   Of Rohan!
>   My brothers.
>   I see in your eyes the same fear that would take the heart of me.
>   A day may come when the courage of Men fails, when we forsake our friends and break all bonds of fellowship, but it is not this day.
>   An hour of wolves and shattered shields when the Age of Men comes crashing down, but it is not this day!
>   This day we fight!
>   By all that you hold dear on this good earth, I bid you stand, Men of the West!

While rewatching this scene recently, what caught my eye was the line about fear:

> I see in your eyes the same fear that would take the heart of me.

My interpretation of this is that Aragorn imagines himself as a random soldier in his army and what it must look like to face impossible odds and almost certain death. Had he been in such a case, he might had been a coward.

However, we know that Aragorn is not a coward and this was just a way to inspire his troops and develop camaraderie. Still, at some point during any of the numerous battles or perilous trips in hostile territory throughout his long life there might have been moments when he had expressed fear, e.g. on the road from Dunharrow to the Paths of the Dead or when facing the Nine (Five!?) at Weathertop.

So, my question is: **Has Aragorn ever expressed fear, e.g. when talking to a companion or in internal dialog?**

Answers from both the books and the movies will be accepted.

Comment: There's a big difference between being afraid and being a coward. Bravery is all about overcoming fear; the more intense the fear, the greater the bravery in facing it.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**I think yes**

> You may escape from Bree, and be allowed to go forward while the Sun
> is up; but you won’t go far. They will come on you in the wild, in
> some dark place where there is no help. Do you wish them to find you?
> **They are terrible!’ The hobbits looked at him, and saw with surprise
> that his face was drawn as if with pain, and his hands clenched the
> arms of his chair.** The room was very quiet and still, and the light
> seemed to have grown dim. For a while he sat with unseeing eyes as if
> walking in distant memory or listening to sounds in the Night far
> away. ‘There!’ he cried after a moment, drawing his hand across his
> brow. ‘Perhaps I know more about these pursuers than you do. **You fear
> them, but you do not fear them enough, yet.** Tomorrow you will have to
> escape, if you can. Strider can take you by paths that are seldom
> trodden. Will you have him?’

FotR, Chapter 10 - "Strider"

He does not say it openly, but I think his body language expresses that he has very unpleasant memories about the riders, and that he fears a close encounter with them. Normally Aragorn can perfectly control and conceal his fear, but now he can use it to his advantage, showing the hobbits that the Nine are not to be taken lightly.

And also in Book II, Ch 4 - "A journey in the dark":

> ‘The road that I speak of leads to the Mines of Moria,’ said Gandalf.
> Only Gimli lifted up his head; a smouldering fire was in his eyes. On
> **all** the others a **dread fell** at the mention of that name. Even to the
> hobbits it was a legend of vague fear. ‘The road may lead to Moria,
> but how can we hope that it will lead through Moria?’ said Aragorn
> darkly. [...]’
>
> ‘I too once passed the Dimrill Gate,’ said Aragorn quietly; ‘but though I
> also came out again, **the memory is very evil. I do not wish to enter Moria a
> second time.**[...]
>
> I will follow your lead now – if
> this last warning does not move you. It is not of the Ring, nor of us others that
> I am thinking now, but of you, Gandalf. And I say to you: if you pass the
> doors of Moria, beware!’

Arguably in this case Aragorn expresses two different kinds of fear: He fears Moria for himself, and he has a 'higher order fear' of losing his old friend, teacher and advisor, Gandalf.

And look at this: (Ch 10- "The Breaking of the Fellowship")

> ‘The day has come at last,’ he said: ‘the day of **choice which we have
> long delayed.** What shall now become of our Company that has travelled
> so far in fellowship? Shall we turn west with Boromir and go to the
> wars of Gondor; or turn east to the Fear and Shadow; or shall we break
> our fellowship and go this way and that as each may choose? Whatever
> we do must be done soon.

It seems to me that Aragorn is here (and in the previous chapter) afraid of making the decision. He knows that the decision must be made, and that it would be irreversible and have decisive consequences, and although he had prepared for these times in his whole adult life, he still fears and tries to push the responsibility on Frodo. He had not expected to become leader so soon, and fears that he is not as wise as Gandalf, so he tarries, and that almost leads to catastrophe.

**Conclusion**

Aragorn feels many fears: The fear of the guts when he contemplates encountering things that made him suffer in the past, the fear of the heart when he dreads the loss of his friends, and the fear of the mind when he is suddenly beset with enormous responsibility, and fears that he would turn out an unworthy leader and fall short of his high destiny.

The reason that the reader notices this rarely is twofold. Tolkien scarcely uses his POV: we see him through the eyes of the hobbits, Gimli and even Ioreth, but we never hear his internal monologues. And since he knows that his expressed fear would dishearten his companions and lead him to decisions that further the cause of Sauron, he almost never tells them or lets them influence his deeds. We only see his fears when he is conversing with his most trusted friends and when he uses it as a tool to dissuade others from foolish decisions.

EDIT:

Scanning further, I have found another instance when Aragorn actually admits fear:

> ‘Why are you waiting? What is the matter with you?’ said Gimli in a
> hissing whisper. ‘Legolas is right,’ said Aragorn quietly. ‘We may not
> shoot an old man so, at unawares and unchallenged, whatever **fear or
> doubt be on us.** Watch and wait!’

Two Towers, Ch 5 - "The White Rider"

This is again a different kind of fear. All the previous instances originate from Aragorn's superior knowledge (compared to that of the hobbits or average men). Having been to Imlad Morgul, he knows the true nature of the Black Riders; knowing Gandalf better than any living man, he knows that the Wizard is not as inviolable as the hobbits imagine; knowing geography and the ways of the enemy, he knows that if they go to Gondor they will have no second chance to try to get into Mordor...

Now he does not understand: They have lost the hobbits, the signs are puzzling even to his Ranger tracker-skills, a mysterious old man chased away their horses and is now approaching, he and Legolas feel some queer foreboding in the Forest... It is a great feat of courage and self-control that he does not let their insecurities burst out in violence.

Comment: I also always took Aragorn singing of Luthien on Weathertop as an expression of fear: he's about to face the dreaded Nazgul (you provided the quote from chapter 10), and he's singing of a man triumphing over a terrible, impossible darkness, to come back and marry his beloved, who just happens to be strongly associated with Aragorn's own beloved. Looks to me like a man actively drawing courage from a meaningful story and the thought of the person he loves.

Comment: As I expressed below, I'm unsure if your first quote really expresses Aragorn's fear of the Riders as opposed to his concern for the Hobbits. The second quote however is a good one and certainly one I'd forgotten!

Comment: @Edlothiad Most of the time in the Pony he reasons to the hobbits, but when he remembers his previous encounter with the Nazguls, I am quite sure that he feels anguish: "saw with surprise that his face was drawn as if with pain, and his hands clenched the arms of his chair"

Comment: That's a good point, I think you've absolutely blown the other two answers away with yours and provided the best answer of the three here.

Comment: I can get behind that. Well done!

Comment: Thanks. And sorry for incorrect plural 'Nazguls'

Answer (score 6):

## In the films, Aragorn fears his past

Specifically, he fears following in the footsteps of his ancestor, Isildur.

> Arwen: Why do you fear the past? You are Isildur’s heir, not Isildur himself. You are not bound to his fate.
> Aragorn: The same blood flows in my veins. The same weakness.
> Arwen: Your time will come. You will face the same evil, and you will defeat it.
> <sub>[The Fellowship of the Ring - Quotegeek](http://quotegeek.com/quotes-from-movies/the-lord-of-the-rings-the-fel/6211/)</sub>

Aragorn fears that because of his relation he will follow in the footsteps of Isildur, he will fail to become a great King of Men as was destined and instead lead Gondor and Arnor to their demise.

### Books

In the books Aragorn doesn't seem to ever express fear. He is the proud heir of the throne of Men, strong willed and powerful, a memory of the great Men of old, Turin and Beren. There was naught for Aragorn to fear, eventhough two Maia, Sauron and Saruman, both feared him, and with reason.

With respect to the above, Aragorn never doubts his rights to the throne in the books. He knows that he has a destiny to fulfil and he never doubts his path. He fears not his past, instead he looks to improve and be better than the failures of Isildur.

> Did you say aught to – him? Even Gandalf feared that encounter.’
> ‘You forget to whom you speak,’ said Aragorn sternly, and his eyes glinted.
> <sub>Return of the King - Book V, Chapter 2: The Passing of the Grey Company</sub>

From the two points you mention, Aragorn shows no fear for the Nine at Weathertop, jumping out to face all five Ringwraiths that are present, and defending the fear-struck Hobbits

> Even as he swooned he caught, as through a swirling mist, a glimpse of Strider leaping out of the darkness with a flaming brand of wood in either hand.

Aragorn shows no fear for the Paths of the Dead and is willing to take whatever route he must to travel East the swiftest:

> I will ride east by the swiftest way, and I will take the Paths of the Dead.
> <sub>Return of the King - Book V, Chapter 2: The Passing of the Grey Company</sub>

He rode through the paths without fear and summoned the dead without second thought:

> Then Elrohir gave to Aragorn a silver horn, and he blew upon it; and it seemed to those that stood near that they heard a sound of answering horns, as if it was an echo in deep caves far away.
> <sub>ibid.</sub>

Comment: Saying that Aragorn acted bravely in some (or many) circumstances is not the same as saying he never feared. Also to say that he did something (i.e. took the Path of the Dead) does not mean he was not frightened of it.

Comment: ^ exactly. if Aragorn had no fear at all, he would be foolhardy, not brave.

Comment: He may have feared, but this is never openly expressed.

Comment: ...except for the half-dozen examples I cited :D ;)

Comment: None of those are him being afraid of something or someone, but concerned for the protection of others, either way I feel neither of our answers was destined to go anywhere ;)

Comment: @Edlothiad - I found another possible instance - what of his statement re: Bill Ferny? Also, I clarified the Pass of Caradhras exchange. He very clearly states he was both afraid of that journey and that he is more afraid of other things [but what those are goes unstated]

Answer (score 2):

**Yes**

On several occasions in the book, Aragorn / Strider has said that he feared or worried about something. This is not to say that he has ever been cowardly or reticent to take action, or lacking boldness. *Healthy knowledge and fear of your enemy is a valid character trait of the brave and heroic*.

Gandalf and Aragorn both were afraid that the Pass of Caradhras would be too perilous. This interchange is particularly telling, because it indicates that Aragorn is aware that he has fear of not just one thing, but several and that **he fears some things more than others**:

[it is unstated what he fears *more* than, but the statement itself implies that such things do exist]

> *"This is what I feared", he [Gandalf] said. "What do you say now, Aragorn?"*
>
> *That **I feared it too, but less than other things**", Aragorn answered.*

- FoTR: Book Two - Chapter 3 - The Ring Goes South

It is worth noting as a secondary instance, regarding the journey through the Paths of the Dead and to Gondor, that Gimli states:

> **"But still, Aragorn was driven by fear that time was too short."**

- Ch 9 - The Last Debate

*This comment is open to interpretation/doubt though as it is another character speaking as to the thoughts of another, not the narrator or character themselves stating it.*

Another example is Strider/Aragorn stating that he is concerned of Bill Ferny talking about what he [Ferny] has seen and what direction the group is headed:

> "He [Bill Ferny] knows the land round here well enough, but he knows he
>   is no match for me in a wood. **It is what he may tell others that I am
>   afraid of**."

- Chapter 11 - A Knife in the Dark

Other examples of Aragorn stating a fear or concern from the book, as the question asked:

Here - Aragorn seems to be indicating that he is uncertain of what is coming upon him and hobbits at Weathertop, and that he fears it is the Black Riders.

> *"I do not know, but **I fear the worst**", answered Strider*

- Chapter 11 - A Knife in the Dark

Later - he is looking for tracks and clues as to who may have been in the area, but, he was afraid that the important clues would be lost due to the hobbits movements.

> *"It is **just as I feared**", he said when he came back. "Sam and Pippin have trampled the ground".*

- Chapter 11 - A Knife in the Dark

Finally, from the Appendix:

> "For a moment Aragorn gazed in silence, but **fearing that she would
>   pass away and never be seen again**, he called to her crying Tinuviel,
>   Tinuviel! even as Beren had done in the Elder Days long ago."

Comment: None of these are actual examples of fear. Their merely what he was worried about. He is not expressing his fear of the Nine Riders. Nor is he afraid of the circumstances. He is merely aware that it hasn't turned out the best for their situation, in my opinion that is not fear, at least not for himself.

Comment: @Edlothiad - the question states:  "Has Aragorn ever expressed fear, e.g. when talking to a companion or in internal dialog?" - I listed examples of Aragorn saying the actual words and that earns a downvote?

Comment: So Aragorn is also afraid of not having Gollum's love? _He will never love me, I fear; for he bit me, and I was not gentle._ The downvote is for your misunderstanding of the character.

Comment: @Edlothiad - I'm not trying to understand the character - I'm answering the question. Also - did I include that quote?

Comment: No but the quote is the same use of the word "fear" as you have included above. And one needs to understand the character Aragorn to answer this question.

Comment: @Edlothiad - then you should vote to close the question as opinion based, as nobody other than the author or possibly Christopher Tolkien has any authority on which to lay claim to an objective understanding of character motivations if you are going to act as arbiter over true meaning of the text. I have now listed several more examples that *do* indicate worry or concern by Aragorn, using the word *fear* as written in the text.

Comment: There's extensive analysis of the character done by dozens of scholars and even by some of the most respected, even by Christopher himself. One doesn't need to be the author to provide an objective literary analysis of a character. You, however have simply searched for every instance of the word fear said by Aragorn and provided them, however have not looked to see what the character might truly fear and whether he truly fears anything or simply worries for his halfling friends.

Comment: Not at all, I was writing the answer before you answered. But you're welcome to come up with whatever opinion of me you choose. You're also welcome to provide criticism on my answer, I feel I've reasoned myself here clearly as to why I've downvoted your answer. I try to answer all tolkien questions, and am the [most active answerer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/tolkiens-legendarium/topusers) in the tag in recent months, it could've been expected that I would answer this one too

Comment: @Edlothiad - Tolkien was a master of language. Aragon uses the word 'fear' to describe his thoughts and concerns nearly constantly. Do you presume to know more than the author and Oxford scholar about the character? If Tolkien didn't mean to use the word 'fear' - he a) wouldn't have b) wouldn't have used it nearly every chapter - I do *not* disagree that Aragorn is brave, bold, and demonstrates no sign of cowardice, but this is not the same as having no fear. One may fear heights and still climb a tower. I'm sorry you dislike the answer and that it doesn't fit your ideal or interpretation

Comment: of the character, but there is simply no arguing against the text. Aragorn feared things. He acted anyway. If the question was asking about cowardice, indeed there would be no examples of such a thing.

Comment: You're suggesting that the fear op is looking for is concern, this is one interpretation, an interpretation I disagree with. I have expressed my disagreement. I don't presume I know more than the author, and never have I stated that. He had those concerns, sure, but I don't believe those are the fears OP is looking for.

Comment: @NKCampbell I'm not downvoting but I fear you do need to understand the character in order to know what he is feeling (fear or worrying)

Comment: @NKCampbell "Bran thought about it. "Can a man still be brave if he's afraid?" "That is the only time a man can be brave," his father told him

Comment: Your first quote is the only example of fear, the rest are just expressions.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot - the question *literally* asks: "Has Aragorn ever expressed fear?" - yes, numerous times, all over the text. And - even if only ONE of the quotes above counts, that would still, by definition, be a 'yes'

Comment: And as I said only one of those is expressing fear, the others are something else.

Comment: I fear you are taking the phrasing of several of those quotes too literally.

Comment: "So Aragorn is also afraid of not having Gollum's love?"  Isn't that what we all fear?

Comment: Edlothiad's first comment has a falsehood I must point out: "None of these are actual examples of fear. Their [sic] merely what he was _worried_ about". Worry _is_ fear, and anxiety is fear also. We use these words to downplay fear, but it is fear nonetheless (PS: I am already one of the upvoters)